# how to use select statement with values in insert statement, postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql

I working on Python and PostgreSQL, Now I would like to know, how to use select statement in values statement. for PostgreSQL.

```sql
INSERT INTO table_a 
(A,B,C,D) 
VALUES 
(%s,%s,%s,'SELECT obj_row FROM table_b WHERE #some condition;')
```

```py
statement = """INSERT INTO table_a 
(A,B,C,D) 
VALUES 
(%s,%s,%s,'SELECT obj_row FROM table_b WHERE #some condition;')"""


cur.execute(statement,local_obj)
```

`%s` is use for concante string,
I try to search the familiar topic. 
They said i have to remove VALUES and backet in statement.
So it's possible to use select statement in values?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use a subselect in the `VALUES` expression. Instead, use a `SELECT` with constant values:

```
INSERT INTO table_a (A, B, C, D) 
SELECT %s, %s, %s, obj_row FROM table_b WHERE #some condition
```